# ArcObjects.NET, append with automatic field mapping not working

Tags: arcobjects

I got a strange problem with ArcGIS 10.4 using ArcObjects.NET. By using the code below, if I want to use the Append tool, I have to send it the source and the destination. Both of them are of Object type. So, I can send paramters of type:

IFeatureLayer

IFeatureClass

ITable

String (being the file path)

If I use the files paths, the field mapping is done automatically. But strangely, if I use an IFeatureLayer, IFeatureClass or ITable instance, the fields are not mapped. Even for the ITable, I get all the rows with empty values...

Is it normal? Of course, I can get a workaround by using the files path but when I use a memory FeatureClass, I can only use the IFeatureClass object because there is no file, so, no file path.

```
Dim gp As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor

Dim lAppend As New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Append(source, destination)

lAppend.schema_type = "NO_TEST"
gp.Execute(lAppend, Nothing)
```